# Carbon laravel adding to file name

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I have file upload in my controller and need to add carbon to end of my file so I can insert it into database as unique. I'm doing it like this

```
        $upload->title = Auth::User()->id;
        $current = Carbon::now();
        $file = $request->file('file');
        $file->move(storage_path(). '/', $file->getClientOriginalName());
        $upload->name = $file->getClientOriginalName().$current;
    }
```

My question is this, when showing it to user how can I remove it so that the user sees only file original name(with php I can do it but I would like to use "laravel way")

Comment: Laravel way of what?  This would just be string manipulation, there doesn't have to be a Laravel way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't add `Carbon::now()` to a filename since it has `:` in some filesystems, so do something like this:

```
$current = time(); // Will output something like 1478529571
```

Or if filenames are different and you just want to add date:

```
$current = date('Ymd'); // Will output something like 20161107.
```

Or, if you want to use Carbon:

```
$current = Carbon::now()->format('YmdHs'); // WIll output something like 201611071419
```

Answer (score 1):

As Alexey stated, Carbon::now() returns an object but the __toString() magic method will result in an `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format when it is converted to a string.  To me, this seems like a bad format for a filename and a unix timestamp would be much better.

Moving on, if you wish to store files like this, wouldn't it make sense to store two columns?

```
Filename | Timestamp
---------------------
OriginalFileName | 123456789
```

Save it on the filesystem as `OriginalFileName.123456789` but show it to the client as `OriginalFileName`, no string manipulation required.

I think you'll find most people don't even use the original file name when storing it on the filesystem, they just generate a unique hash and store that  along side the original filename in the database.